# Using promises instead of Observables in my angular services

Tags: angular

My backend server does not notify the client with any new data. so it's only based on traditional request/response.

Can i turn all my services to use promises instead of observable and subscribers?

for example, i want my service to look like:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class HeroService {
    restEndpoint: string;
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
        this.restEndpoint = 'entity'
    }

    get(id?: number): Promise<Entity> {
        return this.http.get<Entity>(environment.apiEndpoint + restEndpoint);
    }

    post(entity: Entity): Promise<Entity> {
        return this.http.post<Entity>(environment.apiEndpoint + restEndpoint);
    }

    put(id: number, entity: Entity): Promise<Entity> {
        return this.http.post<Entity>(environment.apiEndpoint + restEndpoint);
    }

    delete(id: number): Promise<any> {
        return this.http.delete<any>(environment.apiEndpoint + restEndpoint);
    }
}
```

( functions returns promises)

Comment: _My backend server does not notify the client with any new data. so it's only based on traditional request/response._ That does not mean you should abandon observables. The httpclient returns 'cold' observables, which means they are not continuing to emit data, but just emit data once. Why do you want to force the use of Promises?

Comment: You could, but instead of having dozens of operators at your disposal to use the returned observables, you would then only have `.then()` to use the promise.

Comment: @Silvermind that's not what "cold" means. "cold" means that the observable doesn't emit anything until it's subscribed, and that each subscription triggers the process which emits (i.e. sends a request).

Comment: In short Observable are good to use with angular applications.

Comment: Just for curiosity i am asking this. why do you want to use promise instead of observable and subscriber? isn't it working with observable and subscriber or there is any special reason to use promise?

Comment: @JBNizet Ah, I knew that wrong. Thanks for clearing that up. I must have mixed up some things.

Comment: @Kazi i have an application with large use of observables and enpoints. if you don't unsubscrive your subscription inside the component on destroy the susbscription still exist after the compoment gone. i've ended up with 10,000 subscriptions after few minutes

Comment: @shiran that's incorrect. As soon as the response is obtained, the observable returned by the http methods complete, and the observer is automatically subscribed.

Comment: @JBNizet auto unsubscribe happend only if you use them from template. if you subscrive from the components you have to unsubscribe manually.

Comment: No. All observables automatically unsubscribe their observer once they complete or error.

Comment: For reference: *When an Observable issues an OnError or OnComplete notification to its observers, this ends the subscription. Observers do not need to issue an Unsubscribe notification to end subscriptions that are ended by the Observable in this way.* this is from http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html

Answer (score 2):

Just call `toPromise()` after each request

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class HeroService {
    restEndpoint: string;
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
        this.restEndpoint = 'entity'
    }

    get(id?: number): Promise<Entity> {
        return this.http.get<Entity>(environment.apiEndpoint + restEndpoint).toPromise();
    }

    post(entity: Entity): Promise<Entity> {
        return this.http.post<Entity>(environment.apiEndpoint + restEndpoint).toPromise();
    }

    put(id: number, entity: Entity): Promise<Entity> {
        return this.http.put<Entity>(environment.apiEndpoint + restEndpoint).toPromise();
    }

    delete(id: number): Promise<any> {
        return this.http.delete<any>(environment.apiEndpoint + restEndpoint).toPromise();
    }
}
```

PS.: You btw used post within put